# CodePipeline cannot find my Yaml template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, amazon-kms

I am building a CD pipeline using AWS CodePipeline. I fetch my `YAML` template from using S3 bucket as a source for the pipeline, then push it as an output artifactory to be an input to the deployment stage as an input artifactory.

The issue I am facing is that CodePipeline encrypts the `YAML` template and put it in the S3 artifact store, so when CloudFormation looks in the input artifactory it does find the file, since it is name is changed, so how can stop pipeline from encrypting the artifactory?

Here's my CodePipeline CloudFormation template:

```
Resources:
  ArtifactStoreBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled

  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:

      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref 'ArtifactStoreBucket'
        Type: S3

      DisableInboundStageTransitions: []

      Name: !Ref 'PipelineName'

      RoleArn: !GetAtt [PipelineRole, Arn]

      Stages:

        - Name: S3Source
          Actions:
          - Name: TemplateSource
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Source
              Owner: AWS
              Provider: S3
              Version: '1'
            Configuration:
              S3Bucket: !Ref 'S3Bucket'
              S3ObjectKey: !Ref 'CFNTemplateName'
            OutputArtifacts:
              - Name: TemplateSource
                EncryptionDisabled: true
            RunOrder: '1'    

        - Name: DeployToTest
          Actions:
            - Name: CreateChangeSetTest
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CloudFormation
              Configuration:
                ChangeSetName: sample-lambda-dev
                ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
                StackName: sample-lambda-dev
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
                TemplatePath: !Sub "TemplateSource2::${CFNTemplateName}"
                RoleArn: !GetAtt [CFNRole, Arn]
              RunOrder: 1

            - Name: DeployChangeSetTest
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CloudFormation
              Configuration:
                ChangeSetName: sample-lambda-dev
                ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE
                StackName: sample-lambda-dev
                RoleArn: !GetAtt [CFNRole, Arn]
              RunOrder: 2
```

I made sure I am providing the correct artifact and correct template names.

Answer (score 0):

on this line:

> TemplatePath: !Sub "TemplateSource2::${CFNTemplateName}"

is the Artifact named as `TemplateSource2` - but you have no Output-Artifact `TemplateSource2` defined in your template. This has to be renamed.

For `CFNTemplateName`: You already used this in the source-section, to define *where the artifact ( which is a **zip file**) is found on s3*.

When you declare `TemplatePath`, you reference to an artifact and declare the path inside the artifact.

Fromt the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html):

> The location of an AWS CloudFormation template file, which follows the format ArtifactName::TemplateFileName.

Update this line like this:

> TemplatePath: !Sub "TemplateSource::your/path/inside/the/zip/file"

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in the `CreateChangeSetTest` action:

1) It is missing an input artifact section - you have to declare what artifacts are available to each action.
2) The name of the artifact is wrong - you defined a `TemplateSource` output artifact in your source stage, but you're using `TemplateSource2` name.

Change the step to the following:

```
            - Name: CreateChangeSetTest
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Deploy
            Owner: AWS
            Version: 1
            Provider: CloudFormation
          Configuration:
            ChangeSetName: sample-lambda-dev
            ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
            StackName: sample-lambda-dev
            Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
            TemplatePath: !Sub "TemplateSource::${CFNTemplateName}"
            RoleArn: !GetAtt [CFNRole, Arn]
          RunOrder: 1
          InputArtifacts:
            - Name: TemplateSource
```